# Fastest/most minimal way to check if string contains multiple words

Tags: c++, string

I'm using c++11, and can use regex stuff. I'm wondering what's the fastest way to check if a string contains multiple words, and if so how many. Words in this case are defined as groups of characters separated by whitespace.

I have a few options:

1. Split string by whitespace, count length of split
2. Use some sort of regex
3. Count whitespace characters

Option 1 is the easiest way, but accounting for multiple whitespace characters makes splitting a bit more complicated. 2 is probably slower and I'm not sure how I'd get a count out of it. 3 is the fastest I can think of, but there are probably many corner cases to consider. I would like my solution to be as efficient as possible and include as little extra libraries as possible. It's a solvable problem for me, but I need more insight as to what the *best* solution is.

I'm leaning towards the first, but then what functions would be best? `istringstream` plus an iterator, `stringstream`, some `char*` magic? I'm not certain what the fastest method would be.

Comment: The _best_ solution is whatever fits your needs most. Do you need it to be fast, or easy to read/maintain? You could always write all three, run benchmarks on them, and see which on you'd prefer to use.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I added a little bit more clarification.

Comment: If you want to find similar words in the string, I think that you have to store each word in the vector and than sort it. In this case similar words will be located one by one in the sequence. Here you get the next complexity O(NlogN)+O(N) ( sort + check each element in the vector ).

Comment: It's not a big problem, it might be worth doing some experiments, it will help you to learn benchmarking code. It's not something you'll need to do all the time but this is a good fit. for your case anything that doesn't allocate memory (e.g. counting) has a good chance of being faster than things that will allocate memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate through the string, counting the words and iterating over any consecutive whitespace.

- Increase word count whenever moving from whitespace to non-whitespace.
- Increase word count if string starts with non-whitespace

  ```
  int countWords(string& toCount, const string& whitespace){
      enum countStatus {
          startOfString,
          initialWhitespace,
          movePastWord,
          movePastWhitespace
      } status=startOfString;    

      int wordCount=0;

      for(char& c : toCount) {
          bool characterIsWhitespace=false;

          if (whitespace.find(c)!=string::npos) {
              characterIsWhitespace=true;
          }

          switch(status) {
              case startOfString:
                  if (characterIsWhitespace) {
                      status=initialWhitespace;
                  } else {
                      status=movePastWord;
                      wordCount++;
                  }
              break;

              case initialWhitespace:
                  if (!characterIsWhitespace) {
                      wordCount++;
                      status=movePastWord;
                  }
              break;

              case movePastWord:
                  if (characterIsWhitespace) {
                      status=movePastWhitespace;
                  }
              break;

              case movePastWhitespace:
                  if (!characterIsWhitespace) {
                      wordCount++;
                      status=movePastWord;
                  }
          }
      }

      return wordCount;
  }
  ```

Comment: I'd have posted all the code, including int main() etc, but I spent longer battling with trying to get #include to format correctly that writing this method.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you could utilize an associative container. C++ has a variety of choices. For example, you can utilize `std::map`. In the following code, you can count how many multiple words occur in text.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,int> strCount;
    std::string str("AA BB ABC AA GE AAf FF JJ BB CC "); 
    std::string temp;

    // Split String Based on Whitespace (i.e. you need to modify it to suit the text format you have. )
    for ( int i(0); i < str.size(); ++i ){
        temp += str[i];
        if ( str[i] == ' ' ){
            temp.pop_back();
            ++strCount[temp]; // <-- if element new, insert it in map and associate new counter, otherwise increment counter of element. 
            temp.clear();
       }
    }


    std::map<std::string,int>::const_iterator iter;   
    for( iter = strCount.begin(); iter != strCount.end(); iter++ ) {
        std::cout << "#: " << iter->second << " string: " << iter->first << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the preceding code is

```
#: 2 string: AA
#: 1 string: AAf
#: 1 string: ABC
#: 2 string: BB
#: 1 string: CC
#: 1 string: FF
#: 1 string: GE
#: 1 string: JJ
```